# How to use rescue in rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I have a rake task like this:

```
task :update_all => :environment do
        codes = get_all_codes
        codes.each{ |code| find_or_create_from_my_data(code) }
end
```

Sometimes the update fails, so I want to know with which code failed.
For that I wrote like this:

```
task :update_all => :environment do
    begin
        codes = get_all_codes
        @code
        codes.each{ |code| @code = code; find_or_create_from_my_data(code) }
    rescue
        p @code
    end
end
```

It works fine, but I think it's a bit redundant. How can I write more effectively?

Comment: FYI for passers-by: you need to use `begin` and `end` in your `task` to be able to `rescue`, which isn't the case with `def`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
task :update_all => :environment do
  get_all_codes.each do |code|
    begin
      find_or_create_from_my_data(code)
    rescue
      p code
    end
  end
end
```

This way, even if one code fails, it will print it out and move on to the other ones instead of aborting early.

Comment: It look much better than mine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

the e.message will display for you which code failed and why

```
task :update_all => :environment do
    codes = get_all_codes
    codes.each{ |code| find_or_create_from_my_data(code) }
  rescue => e
    puts "(#{e.message})"
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately `e.message` doesn't contain `code` variable, and different from `def`, `rescue` clause can not use in `task`.